# Can someone please review my code for an HTTP request to the Yelp API?

Tags: javascript, http, web, cors

My code that makes the request is the following:

```
    const fetchData = async (e) => {
           const BASE_URL = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search"

            e.preventDefault();   
            setHome(false)

            try{
                const rawData = console.log(await fetch(`${BASE_URL}?location=ny&term=pizza`, {
                    headers: {
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
                    }
                }))
                
                const res = await rawData.json();
                setRestaurants(res.businesses)
                setParams({
                    term: "",
                    location: ""
                })
    
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error)
            }
        }
```

This is triggered by this form onSubmit:

```
<form onSubmit={fetchData} >
                <input onChange={createParams} type="text" name="term" required="required" placeholder="Search for a food or restaurant" value={params.term}/>
                <input onChange={createParams} type="text" name="location" required="required" placeholder="Search for a location" value={params.location}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
</form>
```

For some reason, I continuously receive these errors:

```
GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.yelp.com/v3/businesses/search?location=nj&term=pizza 403 (Forbidden)

SyntaxError: Unexpected token S in JSON at position 0
```

There is not much code left that I can show you all besides the state that sets my 'params' & 'restaurants'. I am not sure what else to do.

Comment: You are supposed to call the API via a server-to-server call, and cors-anywhere is shutting you down because it's only meant for testing.

Answer (score 3):

[image: CORS Anywhere homepage]

[CORS Anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) should only be used for development purposes. The error message you got in the console states that your request to `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` was rejected with a `403 Forbidden` error for the aforementioned reason.

I must note that depending on an external CORS proxy in production is a dangerous idea. If you absolutely need one setting up your own proxy is the most reliable option. Also, when a website or API is protected by CORS, it is likely intended for internal use.

Comment: You are right it's a dangerous idea, so don't recommend it!

Comment: @Evert You're correct, I've edited my answer.